# Involvement of a Heaviside Theta function inside an integral and its physical significance

Tags: scattering, greens-functions, classical-field-theory

I tried to study some scattering problem and I face the following integral-
$$\int_{-a}^a \, dy_0\int_{-b}^b \, dz_0\int_0^{\infty}dt_0 \exp (-i\omega t_0)\frac{\delta (t_0-(t-\frac{s(t)}{c}))}{s(t)}$$
where, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $t_0$ and $t$ represents time and $s(t)=\sqrt{d^2+(y-y_0)^2+(vt-z+z_0)^2}$, represents time dependent position and $v$ is some constant.
This is noteworthy that $\frac{\delta (t_0-(t-\frac{s(t)}{c}))}{s(t)}$ is the retarded Green's function for an wave equation and some disturbance is propagating from one point to another point such that $|\vec{r(t)}-\vec{r(t_0)}|=s(t)$

If I first do the time integral, I expect the result is $\Theta(t-\frac{s(t)}{c})\frac{\exp (-i\omega((t-\frac{s(t)}{c}))}{s(t)}$

where by definition of Heaviside Theta function [due to causality here], $\Theta(t-\frac{s(t)}{c})= 1,  \forall t>\frac{s(t)}{c}\\
= 0, \forall  t<\frac{s(t)}{c}$

**1)** Now my first question is for the next spatial integral is this Theta function (as being dependent of $y_0$ and $z_0$) is required to be taken inside the integral and integrate over it also or  it will come outside the integral as a simple constant $1$ as defined above. In that case, if it is taken inside the integral what is the physical significance it holds?

Further, is this true that for the time integral Theta function is necessary. If for simplicity,I do the all integrals first and then use the Theta function as a cutoff will that be physically incorrect?

**2)** If the following approximation is taken as appropriate for the problem such that $y=z=0$ [the observation point is on the X axis] and $d$ and $vt$ are comparable and $d>>y_0,z_0$. So, using this $$s(t)\approx s_0Q(1+z'/Q^2)$$
where, $vt=s_0$ and $Q^2=1+d^2/s_0^2$ and $z'=z/s_0$.This $s_0$ and $Q$ are constants.

There the integral becomes
$$\int_{-a}^a \, dy_0\int_{-b/x_0}^{b/x_0} \, dz'\Bigg(\Theta(t-s_0Q(1+z'/Q^2))\times\exp -i\omega(s_0Q(1+z'/Q^2))\times\frac{(1-z'/Q^2)}{s_0Q}\Bigg)$$
Sir, Would you kindly suggest me how can I solve this integral or any reference from where I can get some help.

Answer (score 1):

As the Theta function depends explicitly on $s$, which is a function of $y_0$ and $z_0$, it cannot be pulled out of the integral. Due to the Theta function, when integrating over $y_0$ and $z_0$, only values for which $\sqrt{d^2+(y-y_0)^2+(vt+z-z_0)^2} \leq ct$ will contribute.

Comment: Ok Sir, but is this true that for the time integral Theta function is necessary. If  for simplicity,I do the all integrals first and then use the Theta function as a cutoff will that be physically incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean. The theta function is the *result* of the time integral, you cannot integrate over time without getting it. If you are asking about the order of integration then it doesn't matter what you integrate first, however for any choice you will get a theta function after one integral, as the result of the delta-function in the integrand. If you are asking if you can integrate without the delta function and then put by hand some theta function at the end, then the answer is no - you will get the wrong result

Comment: Sir, as you told I have posted the spatial integral including Theta function. Would you kindly help me how can I do this integral..